# Multiple Actionscript 3 layers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, layer

I'm wondering if I split up certain bits of code that are meant for different sections into different layers will they have functionality between them or act as separate things. (will I be able to reference a variable on one layer from the other?)

Basically I have a set of code that runs throughout every frame but also need code specific to certain frames but still be able to access the main code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could have code that spans multiple frames as well as individual frame script:

[image: timeline]

In this case, individual key frame script from `actions` layer could call functions defined in `main actions`, likewise `main actions` can call functions from code within the current frame of `actions` layer.

As applications increase in complexity, you may want to consider using classes over frame script, defining a base document class for your project.

[image: document class]

As well, define classes per symbols in the library through AS Linkage:

[image: library]

There are many design patterns for larger applications to reduce complexity.