# How can I have the same Actionscript 3.0 execute anywhere along the timeline?

Tags: c#, actionscript-3, flash

I have a movie with multiple layers. On the action layer I have an Actionscript 3.0 script in the first frame. In the text layer I have text that moves across the stage a total of 240 frames. The swf is called from a C# program.

The problem I'm having is that the actionscript is not executing unless the movie is in frame 1 of the timeline. If I try to call a function at any other time nothing happens. If I try to copy the keyframe from frame 1 into any other frame I receive an error that there are duplicate functions/variables. Is there a way to call the same script anywhere on the timeline?

Thanks for the help.

Gary

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11445563/multiple-actionscript-3-layers

The answer to your question is detailed there.

Comment: I seem to have it setup the way this question shows. There isn't much detail in the answer so I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each frame of a movie clip stay separate, but in the end look at the concept of `this` is all the same object. if assume 1 frame have a function name is `doStuff()`, to another frame `doStuff()` function you can copy all of frame, not available you've got duplicate violation. becuase all frame is eventually same MovieClip reference. Only difference is that frame.

this is three options for a solution.

> 1. Every frame is the define the function name with a different name
> 2. 1 frame write a script code in a Main Stage Frame. and the other symbol inner frame work the function call.
> 3. if a change frame each frame should dispatchEvent. and a listen this event a MainStage Frame and control it.

Comment: Thank you bitmapdata.com for the reply. I'm not sure I understand the last couple of options. What is the MainStage Frame? I was wondering if you could explain them a little futher. Thanks.

Comment: I used the third option. I created a document Main class and put all of the functionality into it. I then created a script in the first frame of the action layer that consisted of nothing but the ExternalInterface.addCallback statements that referenced functions in the Main class, I then copied frame 1 to all 240 frames. This worked great!! Thanks!!